# Weight exerted on scale by balloon filled with ideal gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I want to compute the weight of a spherical balloon (with radius $r$) in vacuum filled with ideal gas. The balloon is laying on a scale. Using the barometric formula $$ P(h)=P(h_0) e^{-\alpha(h-h_0)},$$ where $\alpha = M g/ RT $ I want to figure out what the scale will read. Wikipedia says the formula works for an ideal gas. $P(h)$ is the pressure  as a function of the height $h.$ $M$ is the molar mass, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration, $R$ is the gas constant and $T$ is the temperature. $h_0$ is the reference height.

Is it right to say: Since the particles only transfer their momentum to the balloon , when they impact its boundary we can sum all these contributions up to get the net weight?

I thought since pressure is force per area, on a small area $dA$ with normal vector $\vec{n},$ the force pushing that piece of the balloon in direction of $\vec{n}$ is $d\vec{F}= \vec{n} P dA. $ Now I just integrate over the balloon surface and get the net force acting on the balloon. $$\vec{F}=\oint_{Surface} d\vec{F}.$$

Suppose we have a spherical coordinate system where the balloon is sitting on a height $h_0$ then $h = h_0+(1+\cos\theta) r.$ And the force

$$
\vec{F}=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}d\theta \, d\phi \, r^2 \sin\theta  \,\vec{n}(\theta, \phi)\, P(h_0+(1+\cos\theta)r).
$$

Now, since the the force magnitude for a specific $\theta$ is the same for all $\phi$  and we got radial symmetry, we can say the horizontal components of the net force must be 0. So, we only need to compute the 'heihgt component' $F_z.$ For this we only need the same component for the normal vector $n_z = -\cos\theta.$

Finally $$
F_z = \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}d\theta \, d\phi \, r^2 \sin\theta  \,\cos\theta \, P(h_0)e^{-\alpha(1+\cos\theta)r)} \\ = 
\int_{u=1}^{-1} 2\pi \frac{-1}{\sin\theta} du \, r^2 \sin\theta  \,u \, P(h_0)e^{-\alpha(1+u)r)}= 2\pi r^2  P(h_0)e^{-\alpha r}\int_{u=-1}^{1} du  \,u \, e^{-\alpha u r} \\ = 2\pi  P(h_0)e^{-\alpha r}\frac{\sinh \alpha r  - \alpha r \cosh \alpha r}{\alpha^2}.
$$

Also, if this is true, is there a shorter way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes there is a shorter way.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle  The reading on the scale is just the weight of the balloon and gas inside minus the weight of the air displaced.

Comment: @puppetsock Why can I use that principle for the ideal gas? Also, just for clarification the balloon is in vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

It is the weight of the gas minus the weight of the volume of air it displaces. You need to find the volume the balloon will occupy from the ideal gas law and the spring action of the balloon.